# Server-Side Code Reads Old Control Value After Javascript Update

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

Complicated title, that.  I'm still getting the hang of how client-side and server-side code interacts, so be kind if I'm being stupid.

Basically, I have a server-side hidden *HiddenField* on an ASP.NET Web Form page.  When I click a control elsewhere on the page, a Javascript function is called which updates the value of the *HiddenField*, and also triggers a postback.  However, when I subsequently read the value of the *HiddenField* after postback, even though I've definitely changed it with Javascript (I know it works because I tried swapping the *HiddenField* for a *Label* so I could actually see that it had changed), the value that is read is the old value, as it was before the Javascript changed it.

I'm guessing there's something I'm not understanding about how changing the value of a control with Javascript doesn't update it in the server's view of the page, but I'm a bit stuck.  I've posted some very simplified code below to try and illustrate my problem.

**ASP**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Before" OnClientClick="this.value = 'After'" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnTest" EventName="click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Before click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

**VB.NET Code Behind**

```
Protected Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click

    lblTest.Text = btnTest.Text

End Sub
```

When this page is loaded, if you click the Button *btnTest*, the text on the Button is changed to 'After' by the Javascript in the Button's `OnClientClick` property.  However, the code behind, in evaluating the Button's text, still returns 'Before' when populating the Label *lblTest*.

The Label is in an *UpdatePanel* because otherwise clicking the button triggers a full-page postback, and the text of *btnTest* reverts to 'Before', which I also don't quite understand because the Button is a server-side control (it has `runat=server` specified), so surely its text should be stored in the page's ViewState when the postback occurs?

Comment: You should see you `Page_Load` method. There might be something reverting the text of the button there...

Comment: Page_Load is empty.  The code above is literally all there is on the page and the code behind.